# fish: swallow flags from $argv (context: replace rm with KDE trash)

Tags: fish

I already have most of it working but I want to swallow flags so I don't get an error like this:

```sh
/t/temp-5969 $ trash -rf fish-functions/
kioclient: Unknown option 'rf'.
kioclient: Use --help to get a list of available command line options.
```

I have this so far:

```sh
/t/temp-5969 $ type trash
trash is a function with definition
function trash
    kioclient move $argv trash:/
end
```

(to replace rm: `abbr rm trash`)

I want it to ignore `-rf` so it will still work either way so my muscle memory doesn't mess up when I switch between bash and fish

To accomplish this I want to build a function to swallow the flags from `$argv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this

```
function trash
    while test (count $argv) -gt 0
        switch $argv[1]
            case --
                set argv $argv[2..-1]
                break
            case '-*'
                set argv $argv[2..-1]
            case '*'
                break
        end
    end

    kioclient move $argv trash:/
end
```

It would be nice if `argparse` could help, but that works when you know specifically what options you need to parse.

Note you may still be "vulnerable": to deal with filenames starting with a dash, you can do

```
rm -- -filename-starts-with-a-dash
rm ./-filename-starts-with-a-dash
```

With your function, you'll have to use the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function like this:

```sh
function swallowFlags
    sed 's/-\w\+//'
end

function trash
    kioclient move (echo $argv | swallowFlags) trash:/
end
```

but maybe there is a less weird way to do this so I don't have to use echo?

ahh.. I probably need a better regex so that I can delete files that have dashes in them lol